# How to create a Datanucleus JPA 2.x query with CriteriaQuery that is based on values from an embedded map

Tags: datanucleus, jpa-2.1

Basically, I have an Entity (Simplified for question) like below:

```
@Entity
public class MyClass {

@Id
private String id;

@Basic
private String name;

@Embedded
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name="configName")
@Column(name="configValue")
@CollectionTable
private Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();

...
}
```

When I construct a query with DataNucleus CriteriaQuery for JPA 2.x, I have a query value of:

Map> queryInput ......

where queryINput holds value like:

```
("k1", ("v1", "v3"))
("k2", ("v2", "v4"))
("k3", ("v3"))
```

Let's say config of (one MyClass instance) holds value as below:

```
("k1", ("v1"))
("k2", ("v2"))
("k3", ("v3"))
```

What I want to achieve is to search MyClass whenever all the keys of the input map matches all the keys of the config map and for each matched key, the value of the config map is in one of the values in the input map values, I will return MyClass. In the example above, the instance will be returned as it satisfy the criteria.

and both the below will fail:

```
("k1", ("v1"))
("k2", ("v2"))
//fail because k3 doesn't present.
```

or

```
("k1", ("v2")) //fail because v2 value is not in the query value list for key k1
("k2", ("v2"))
("k3", ("v3"))
```

How am I able to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm doing something conceptually similar, but different technologies: Scala with JDO. If you are interested, please have a look at http://github.com/frgomes/poc-scala-datanucleus